# .htaccess ReWrite URL including the query string

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to use `mod_rewrite` to map URLs like

```
http://www.example.com/dir/something?foo=bar&stack=overflow
```

to

```
http://www.example.com/dir/process.php?action=something&query_string=foo%3Dbar%3Fstatck%3Doverflow
```

without redirecting. That means the URL in visitor's browser should be the former, but should actually work like the latter. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^dir/(.+)$ /dir/process.php?action=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

QSA flag will automatically append the addtitional query perameters to the target url.

Comment: Your answer converted the URL to `dir/process.php?action=something&foo=bar&stack=overflow`. But what I wanted was to convert it to `dir/process.php?action=something&query_string=foo%3Dbar%3Fstatck%3Doverflow`. **Note**: I don't want to append the additional parameters, instead pass them under another parameter `query_string`.